# Retrieve objectId in Parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

In simple, I am trying to retrieve the objectId for a particular user in parse (using Javascript). I can retrieve any other query in the database, such as username, phone, mailing address but not the objectId, here is how I retrieve the rest of the query:

```
     var objectId = userInfo.get("objectId");
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Below is more lines of the code (everything is retrieved beside objectId)

```
query.find({ success: function(array) {

           // this means the query was a success, but we're not yet certain that we found anything
           // the param to find's success is an array of PFObjects, possibly empty

           if (array.length > 0) {
               var userInfo = array[0];
               var address = userInfo.get("address");
               $scope.address = address;

               var email = userInfo.get("username");
               $scope.email = email;


          var fullName = userInfo.get("fullName");
               $scope.fullName=  fullName;

             var number = userInfo.get("phoneNumber");
               $scope.number=  number;


             var objectId = userInfo.get("objectId");
               $scope.objectId=  objectId;

          var mailingAddress = userInfo.get("mailingAddress");
               $scope.mailingAddress =  mailingAddress;

             var plan = userInfo.get("plan");
               $scope.plan =  plan;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The js sdk provides an `id` member, so ...

```
$scope.objectId = userInfo.id;
```

As an aside, [check out the JS guide](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide) on their site.  It's a very well written doc.  Pay particular attention to the code snippets in the objects and query sections.